# Where's a good place to find Information on Non-OCED countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, balance-of-trade, national-accounts, balance-of-payments

I'm looking for Private Savings (Sp), Investment (I), Taxes (T), Government Spending (G) for India.

Answer (score 1):

The [IMF Data](https://www.imf.org/en/Data), the [UN Country Data](http://data.un.org/countryData/Home/Countries) or the [World Bank Open Data](https://data.worldbank.org/country/india) should be good data sources covering a wide range of countries.